# Receber status da requisição http client e token de login no angular

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

Minha api do backend retorna um token e um status, preciso guardar o token no localstorage e redirecionar o usuário para a tela de boas vindas caso o status retornado da api for 200.

Tentei algo como:

**usuario.model.ts:**

```
export class Usuario{
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

**login.component.ts:**

```
 usuario: Usuario = new Usuario();

     fazerLogin(email: string, password: string): void{
        this.loading = true;
        this.authService.fazerLogin(email,password)

          .subscribe(

            (resp) => {
              console.log(resp);
            },

            (data) => {
                if(data == null){ //se o retorno da requisição for null, aciona a função que exibe o toast
                  this.toastUsuarioIncorreto();
                  this.authService.setUsuarioEstaAutenticado(false);
                  this.loading = false;
                }else{ //emite para o serviço que o usuário foi autenticado e que pode acessar as rotas do guard, redireciona para a home
                  this.authService.setUsuarioEstaAutenticado(true);
                  let token = JSON.stringify(data); //aqui é recebido o id do usuário
                  this.token = token; //aqui passa o valor do id do usuário para a variável do componente
                  localStorage.setItem('currentUser', this.token);
                  this.loading = false;
              }
            },
          );
        }
```

**auth.service.ts:**

```
  fazerLogin(email: string, password: string): Observable<HttpResponse<any>>  {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT,
    {
      email: email,
      password: password
    },
    {
      headers: headers
    },


  )}
```

O meu console.log só retorna o token, e eu preciso do token e do status pra validar.
Socorro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, na sua classe Auth.service.ts, adicione a importação:

```
import { map, catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Após isso, altere o seu auth.service.ts

```
fazerLogin(email: string, password: string): Observable<HttpResponse<any>>  {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT,
               {email: email, password: password },
               { headers: headers, observe: 'response' })
          .pipe(
              map((response) => ({data: response.body, status: response.status}))
           );
    }
```

Altere o seu método fazerLogin para o seguinte...

```
usuario: Usuario = new Usuario();

 fazerLogin(email: string, password: string): void{
    this.loading = true;
    this.authService.fazerLogin(email,password).subscribe((response) => {
          // aqui você faz o seu processamento, acessando data e status do objeto declarado acima.

         let data = response.data;
         let statusCode = response.status;

         if(data == null){ //se o retorno da requisição for null, aciona a função que exibe o toast
              this.toastUsuarioIncorreto();
              this.authService.setUsuarioEstaAutenticado(false);
              this.loading = false;
            }else{ //emite para o serviço que o usuário foi autenticado e que pode acessar as rotas do guard, redireciona para a home
              this.authService.setUsuarioEstaAutenticado(true);
              let token = JSON.stringify(data); //aqui é recebido o id do usuário
              this.token = token; //aqui passa o valor do id do usuário para a variável do componente
              localStorage.setItem('currentUser', this.token);
              this.loading = false;
      })
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Com essas alterações eu tenho: A propriedade .map não existe no tipo Observable<any>

Comment: Ajustei a resposta, obrigado por avisar.

Comment: console.log(data) e console.log(statusCode); retornam undefined

Comment: O tipo 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>' não pode ser atribuído ao tipo 'Observable<HttpResponse<any>>'. Também tentei trocar any para usuario, mas sem sucesso

Comment: Pronto Leticia, alterei de novo, onde você passa os headers, adicione a propriedade observe e troque no método map, o response.json() por response.body